# Merge columns according to keys excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Need to convert this

[image]

Cannot change the above to have `mtown` and `waco` repeated for each rows, since its locked and being imported from else where.

The final result/report should looks like this:

[image]

Want to do this using excel formulas but can't figure it out.

Also want to make it future proof, if another number is added after `43`, it will also change the result/report and add the new number under `mtown`.

---

EDIT: Included image with row and column indexes
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this `=IF(ISTEXT($B$2:$B$14),$B$2:$B$14,$C$2:$C$14)` but then the there's no gap after each of the categories, which I figure I could maybe add using a Count and a if, but the main problem with this is that the number `1` and `12` get skipped.

Comment: Do you have to put `mtown` above `waco`? Or can `waco` be in column `G`?

Comment: Unfortunately, people would freak out if I changed the format. So they need to be in the same column.

Comment: why should it put 43 under motown if a new number is added? And what happens to waco in that scenario? Sounds like a case for VBA.

Comment: Sorry my stupid mistake. I fixed it.

Comment: I agree that VBA is probably going to be the most elegant way to handle this. A formula would be a nightmare (if it's even possible). Also... that is a very strange format to put it in. The "People" that "would freak out" are a strange bunch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick VBA way of doing this.

```
Sub FreakyPeopleFormat()

    Dim rngCell As Range 'cell we are processing
    Dim location As String 'waco, mtown
    Dim lastCell As Integer 'last populated cell on the sheet
    Dim writeCell As Range 'cell to write to

    'set initial write cell
    Set writeCell = Sheet1.Range("F2")

    'get the last cell
    lastCell = Sheet1.Range("C" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row()

    'loop through the data
    For Each rngCell In Sheet1.Range("C2:C" & lastCell)

        'capture location if it's changed
        If location <> rngCell.Offset(, -1).Value And rngCell.Offset(, -1).Value <> "" Then
            If location <> "" Then 'write it out again
                writeCell.Value = location
                'move to next cell and write location
                Set writeCell = writeCell.Offset(1)
            End If

            'capture and write out location
            location = rngCell.Offset(, -1).Value
            writeCell.Value = location
            Set writeCell = writeCell.Offset(1)
        End If

        'process the line
        writeCell.Value = rngCell.Value

        'increment the writeCell
        Set writeCell = writeCell.Offset(1)
    Next

    'finally write out the location once more
    writeCell.Value = location
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was going to sit down and struggle with VBA since I don't know it. You saved me a ton of time and work. I will leave the function name as it is, that's for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub X()

    Dim LR As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rngName As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 1 To LR
            If .Cells(j, 1).Value <> "" And Cells(j, 2).Value <> "" Then
                rngName = .Cells(j, 1).Value

                .Cells(j, 2).Select

                Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
                    If ActiveCell.Offset(, -1).Value <> "" And ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Value = "" Then
                        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Value = ActiveCell.Value
                        ActiveCell.Clear
                    ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(, -1).Value <> "" And ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Value <> "" Then
                        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).EntireRow.Resize(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Value = ActiveCell.Value
                        ActiveCell.Offset(2, -1) = rngName
                        ActiveCell.Clear
                    End If

                   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

                Loop

                ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1) = rngName

            End If
        Next j

    End With

End Sub
```